# where column is null taking longer time to execute

Tags: sql, oracle

I am executing a select statement like the one below which is taking more than 6mins to execute.

```
select * from table where col1 is null;
```

whereas:

```
select * from table;
```

returns results in few seconds. The table contains 25million records. No indexes are used. there is a composite PK but not on the col used. Same query when executed on a different table with 50 million records, returns results in few seconds. only this table poses a problem.

Rebuilt the table to check if there was a miss, but still facing the same issue.

can some one help me here on why it is taking time?
datatype: VARCHAR2(40)
PLAN:

```
Plan hash value: 2838772322

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                       |     1 |   794 | 60973  (16)| 00:00:03 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| table                 |     1 |   794 | 60973  (16)| 00:00:03 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - storage("column" IS NULL)
       filter("column" IS NULL)
```

Comment: Please tag the database engine you’re using and also post the query plan

Comment: Which database server are you using? Have you got an EXPLAIN of the query?

Comment: What  is  your  col1   data type ?

Comment: plan and datatype added: VARCHAR2(40)

Comment: using oracle database

Comment: please look at your post. the format of your plan is unusable. use four blank identation to format it as code

Comment: What kind of SQL client are you using that is able to display 25 million rows "*in few seconds*"?

Comment: Regarding SELECT * FROM TABLE, are you suggesting that you are fetching 25 million records and displaying all the records in a few seconds? Or are you using any tool that restricts the result set? What tool are you using? How many records are displayed?

Comment: i am just doing a data check to understand whether there are any records that has null values. Oracle SQL developer is what we are using

Comment: out of 25million records, very few will have null values not all of them.  some 81 records are getting displayed

Comment: A lot more records have to be read and i/o performed to find matching rows for the null predicate. Makes sense surely?

Answer (score 6):

```
select * from table;
```

Oracle SQL Developer tool has a default setting to display only 50 records unless it was manually edited. So the entire 25 million records will not be fetched as you don't need all the records for display.

```
select * from table where col1 is null;
```

But when you filter for null values, the entire set of 25 million rows has to be scanned to apply the filter and get your 81 records satisfying that predicate. Hence your second query takes longer.